# как избавиться от NaN js

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, localstorage

имею код корзины и при складывании суммы товаров, получаю NaN. Помогите пожалуйста

```
var double_arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("product")) || [];

var total_price = 0;

for(var i = 0; i<double_arr.length;i++)
{
    total_price += parseInt(double_arr[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: `double_arr[i][1]` тут что? `console.log(double_arr[i]);` что показывает скиньте

Comment: все я разобрался, у меня брало число с символом, поэтому не получалось

Comment: удалите вопрос.